# Cannot gcloud builds submit due to a tempfile file.tgz permissions error on Windows

Tags: python, windows, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have an issue running the following command on Windows:

```
gcloud builds submit --timeout=3600s --region=europe-west1 --tag europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/project/project-appengine/project-image:latest
```

It was working fine, but a couple of days ago my deployment script stopped working. Here is what the command returns:

```
Creating temporary tarball archive of 3571 file(s) totalling 25.3 MiB before compression.
ERROR: gcloud crashed (PermissionError): [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp5i8xwo38\\file.tgz'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

I have the latest version of Google Cloud CLI on my Windows 10.

Something is off with file permissions? The archive file is in the directory and is fine. Seems like the SDK cannot access is. Maybe related to the Python version used?

I tried Process Explorer, but found no process locking this file.

> Trace: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\cloudbuild\snapshot.py",
> line 102, in CopyTarballToGCS
> tf = self._MakeTarball(archive_path)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\cloudbuild\snapshot.py",
> line 77, in _MakeTarball
> tf.add(path, filter=_ResetOwnership)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py",
> line 2002, in add
> self.addfile(tarinfo, f)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py",
> line 2030, in addfile
> copyfileobj(fileobj, self.fileobj, tarinfo.size, bufsize=bufsize)   File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py",
> line 254, in copyfileobj
> buf = src.read(remainder)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\crash_handling.py",
> line 199, in Wrapper
> target_function(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\gcloud_main.py", line
> 193, in main
> gcloud_cli.Execute()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line
> 1024, in Execute
> self._HandleAllErrors(exc, command_path_string, specified_arg_names)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line
> 1061, in _HandleAllErrors
> exceptions.HandleError(exc, command_path_string, self._*known_error_handler)   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\exceptions.py",
> line 557, in HandleError
> core_exceptions.reraise(exc)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\exceptions.py",
> line 146, in reraise
> six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\third_party\six_*init**.py", line
> 719, in reraise
> raise value   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line
> 998, in Execute
> resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py",
> line 815, in Run
> resources = command_instance.Run(args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\surface\builds\submit.py", line 234,
> in Run
> build_config = submit_util.SetSource(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\builds\submit_util.py",
> line 428, in SetSource
> staged_source_obj = staging_bucket_util.Upload(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\builds\staging_bucket_util.py",
> line 109, in Upload
> return source_snapshot.CopyTarballToGCS(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\cloudbuild\snapshot.py",
> line 100, in CopyTarballToGCS
> with files.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\files.py",
> line 599, in **exit**
> exceptions.RaiseWithContext(   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\exceptions.py",
> line 180, in RaiseWithContext
> raise curr_exc   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\files.py",
> line 597, in **exit**
> self.Close()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\files.py",
> line 608, in Close
> RmTree(self.path)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\files.py",
> line 262, in RmTree
> shutil.rmtree(path, onerror=_HandleRemoveError)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py",
> line 759, in rmtree
> return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py",
> line 622, in _rmtree_unsafe
> onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\files.py",
> line 244, in *HandleRemoveError
> exceptions.reraise(exc_info[1], tb=exc_info[2])   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\exceptions.py",
> line 146, in reraise
> six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\third_party\six_*init**.py", line
> 719, in reraise
> raise value   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py",
> line 620, in _rmtree_unsafe
> os.unlink(fullname) PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
> 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2j_tooam\file.tgz'

How do I make this command work? Cannot deploy to Google App Engine

**UPD: Solved by manually tgzipping the source files and submitting the build like:**

> gcloud builds submit file.tgz ...

Comment: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`: Did you try restarting your computer?

Comment: @minuu yes I tried, only helped for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PiotrMarkielau, As per recent edit in your post, I can see you have found a work around that solved your issue.Answering it as community wiki for better community visibility.Feel free edit if i miss anything. Work around is

> By manually tgzipping the source files and submitting the build like:
>
> ```
>  gcloud builds submit file.tgz --timeout=3600s --region=europe-west1--tag europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/project/project-appengine/project-image:latest
> ```

Additionally I have found an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/329102380) with 1 Upvote. According to the description over there it looks like an issue at cloud build end. You may consider adding your concern as well and see whether you get any better solution than the workaround you have found.

Comment: Yes.

On windows one can do it like:

tar cfz file.tgz folder1 file1.py, where folder1, file1.py, ... , etc -- are files you want to include in the archive (your source files).